# Tutum Redeploy trigger doesn't rebuild from image

Tags: docker, dockerhub, tutum

Using the web interface of dashboard.tutum.co, when I hit the "Reploy" button on a container, it **doesn't rebuild from my Docker Hub image**. Is that normal behavior?

Here's the context.
I've been trying to implement a *continuous delivery* strategy as follows: Github > Docker Hub > Tutum. It works great, except that in the end the **"latest version" of my website doesn't go live**. To check if it could be a Docker Hub problem, I've terminated my Tutum container and recreated it (using my latest Docker hub image): the latest version of my website is then live.
Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT:**
The problem was that the default redeploy behavior on Tutum is to reuse container volumes. This is why my code wasn't updated!
There's a query parameter called "reuse_volumes" documented [here](https://docs.tutum.co/v2/api/#redeploy-a-service), but I haven't been able to use it successfully with Docker Hub webhooks, so the question still stands.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in the past there was [the `reuse_volumes` parameter in the Stackfile](https://success.docker.com/Tutum/Feature_Reference/Stack_YAML_Reference#reuse_volumes), but it was removed.

Anyway, I worked around this issue by using REST API call to redeploy the service. Since I use Travis CI to build my image, run tests on it and push it to Docker Hub, I've stopped using Docker Hub's webhook and I do a simple cURL call after pushing the image:

```
curl -u $USERNAME:$TUTUM_API_KEY -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"reuse_volumes":false}' https://dashboard.tutum.co/api/v1/service/$SERVICE_UUID/redeploy/
```

It does the job.